# Google Chart Calendar - change value in gradient scale to string

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am using Google Chart Calendar and I would like to modify the gradient values - min and max. From the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar#configuration-options) I can do it by modifying colorAxis:

```
{minValue: 0, maxValue: 5,  colors: ['#FF0000', '#00FF00']}
```

But it supports only type number and I would prefer to indicate it by using string, something like "Lowest value" for minValue and "Highest value" for maxValue.

Any suggestions how can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to calculate the gradient on the 'Activity' column,
options for `minValue` and `maxValue` can only be numbers...

but if you just want to change the label that is displayed on the legend,
that can be done manually on the chart's `'ready'` event

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['calendar']
}).then(function () {
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', id: 'Date'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'number', id: 'Activity'});
  dataTable.addRows([
    [new Date(2018, 0, 3), 1],
    [new Date(2018, 0, 16), 2],
    [new Date(2018, 1, 6), 3],
    [new Date(2018, 1, 15), 4],
    [new Date(2018, 1, 25), 5]
  ]);
  var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  var options = {
    colorAxis: {minValue: 0, maxValue: 5,  colors: ['#FF0000', '#00FF00']},
    width: 1000
  };
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    if ($('#chart_div text').length > 1) {
      $($('#chart_div text').get(0)).text('Lowest');
      $($('#chart_div text').get(1)).text('Highest');
    }
  });
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Oh nice it does work... thank you so much for your help WhiteHat!